# Allow only English letters and numbers in php

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, filter, ansi

I'm trying to create a filter to allow users to use only English letters (Lowercase & uppercase) and numbers. how can I do that? (ANSI)
(not trying to sanitize, only to tell if a string contain non-english letters)
That filter should get me a clean database with only english usernames, without multibyte and UTF-8 characters.

And can anyone explain to me why echo strlen(À) outputs '2'? it means two bytes right? wans't UTF-8 chars supposed to contain a single byte?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php - Take a look at the documentation. *The string being measured for length.*

Comment: UTF-8 is a Unicode Transformation Format. In order to represent all characters, it has one, two, three... byte sequences. You might as well write IsUTF8LeadByte().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you check whether a string contains only letters from the English alphabet.

```
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $string))  {
    //string contains only letters from the English alphabet
}
```

The other question:

```
strlen(À)
```

will not return 2. Maybe you meant

```
strlen('À')
```

`strlen` returns

> The length of the string on success, and 0 if the string is empty.

taken from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). So, that character is interpreted as two characters, probably due to your encoding.

Answer (score 4):

You should use regular expressions to see if a string matches a pattern. This one is pretty simple:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $username)) {
    echo 'Username is valid';
} else {
    echo 'Username is NOT valid';
}
```

And the reason why `strlen('À')` equals **2** is because `strlen` doesn't know that string is UTF-8. Try using:

```
echo strlen(utf8_decode('À'));
```

Comment: will this regular expression match special character à ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't match accented characters, only 26 letters lowercase and uppercase. They need to be added manually to that expression like that: /^[a-zA-Zéèàê0-9]+$/ for instance.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I needed.